# Sticky Table Header Not Changing Width when Window Resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table header sticky at the top when scrolled down.

I am using the solution provided here: css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/.

However when I resize the window, the sticky table header does not resize and match the width of the table columns below. The table header just stays as the fixed size and I am not sure how best to tackle this.

```js
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
       $(".persist-area").each(function() {
           var el             = $(this),
               offset         = el.offset(),
               scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
               floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)
           if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
               floatingHeader.css({
                "visibility": "visible"
               });
           } else {
               floatingHeader.css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
                 });      
               };
           });
        }
            
        $(function() {
           var clonedHeaderRow;
           $(".persist-area").each(function() {
               clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
               clonedHeaderRow
                 .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
                 .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
                 .addClass("floatingHeader");  
           });
           $(window)
            .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
            .trigger("scroll");
        });
```

```css
.floatingHeader {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       visibility: hidden;
     }
.floatingHeader th, .persist-area th, .persist-area td {
       width: 14.285%;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="persist-area">
          <tr class="persist-header">
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
```

How do I make the table columns aligned when windows are resized?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In your solution here it is resizing to match the width of table columns

Comment: Hm no it doesn't. It needs some window resize js function but i'm not sure what

Comment: @Vera check my answer it may be your solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
text-align: left;
```

to your `persist-header` class. Or add it as inline style.

---

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ce9sw31r/).

Comment: hm didn't work - adding text-align: left to persist-header class actually made the sticky effect disappear

Comment: are you sure about that? i've updated the answer with a fiddle link, maybe you could explain how this sticky header should behave in more detail